# RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport => useRepositoryConfiguration => "Reactive Repositories are not supported by %s. Offending repository is %s!"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

with `org.springframework.boot` update from 2.0.4.RELEASE to 2.0.5.RELEASE start to get exception:

> RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport 
>   =>  useRepositoryConfiguration 
>   =>  InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: "Reactive Repositories are not supported by %s. Offending repository is %s!"

what is the best/simplest Spring Data workaround for this? Could someone provide example? if it is possible without redefinition of `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `JpaRepositoriesRegistrar`...

Answer (score 0):

This is solution, but I don't like it.. +3 new classes..
EnableXxxJpaRepositories is practically exact copy of EnableJpaRepositories..

EnableXxxJpaRepositories:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Import(XxxJpaRepositoriesRegistrar.class)
public @interface EnableXxxJpaRepositories {

  /**
   * Alias for the {@link #basePackages()} attribute. Allows for more concise annotation
   * declarations e.g.: {@code @EnableXxxJpaRepositories("org.my.pkg")} instead of {@code
   *
   * @EnableXxxJpaRepositories(basePackages="org.my.pkg")}.
   */
  String[] value() default {};

  /**
   * Base packages to scan for annotated components. {@link #value()} is an alias for (and mutually
   * exclusive with) this attribute. Use {@link #basePackageClasses()} for a type-safe alternative
   * to String-based package names.
   */
  String[] basePackages() default {};

  /**
   * Type-safe alternative to {@link #basePackages()} for specifying the packages to scan for
   * annotated components. The package of each class specified will be scanned. Consider creating a
   * special no-op marker class or interface in each package that serves no purpose other than being
   * referenced by this attribute.
   */
  Class<?>[] basePackageClasses() default {};

  /**
   * Specifies which types are eligible for component scanning. Further narrows the set of candidate
   * components from everything in {@link #basePackages()} to everything in the base packages that
   * matches the given filter or filters.
   */
  Filter[] includeFilters() default {};

  /**
   * Specifies which types are not eligible for component scanning.
   */
  Filter[] excludeFilters() default {};

  /**
   * Returns the postfix to be used when looking up custom repository implementations. Defaults to
   * {@literal Impl}. So for a repository named {@code PersonRepository} the corresponding
   * implementation class will be looked up scanning for {@code PersonRepositoryImpl}.
   */
  String repositoryImplementationPostfix() default "Impl";

  /**
   * Configures the location of where to find the Spring Data named queries properties file. Will
   * default to {@code META-INF/jpa-named-queries.properties}.
   */
  String namedQueriesLocation() default "";

  /**
   * Returns the key of the {@link QueryLookupStrategy} to be used for lookup queries for query
   * methods. Defaults to {@link Key#CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND}.
   */
  Key queryLookupStrategy() default Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND;

  /**
   * Returns the {@link FactoryBean} class to be used for each repository instance. Defaults to
   * {@link JpaRepositoryFactoryBean}.
   */
  Class<?> repositoryFactoryBeanClass() default JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class;

  /**
   * Configure the repository base class to be used to create repository proxies for this particular
   * configuration.
   *
   * @since 1.9
   */
  Class<?> repositoryBaseClass() default DefaultRepositoryBaseClass.class;

  // JPA specific configuration

  /**
   * Configures the name of the {@link EntityManagerFactory} bean definition to be used to create
   * repositories discovered through this annotation. Defaults to {@code entityManagerFactory}.
   */
  String entityManagerFactoryRef() default "entityManagerFactory";

  /**
   * Configures the name of the {@link PlatformTransactionManager} bean definition to be used to
   * create repositories discovered through this annotation. Defaults to {@code
   * transactionManager}.
   */
  String transactionManagerRef() default "transactionManager";

  /**
   * Configures whether nested repository-interfaces (e.g. defined as inner classes) should be
   * discovered by the repositories infrastructure.
   */
  boolean considerNestedRepositories() default false;

  /**
   * Configures whether to enable default transactions for Spring Data JPA repositories. Defaults to
   * {@literal true}. If disabled, repositories must be used behind a facade that's configuring
   * transactions (e.g. using Spring's annotation driven transaction facilities) or repository
   * methods have to be used to demarcate transactions.
   *
   * @return whether to enable default transactions, defaults to {@literal true}.
   */
  boolean enableDefaultTransactions() default true;
}
```

XxxJpaRepositoriesRegistrar:

```
@Configuration
public class XxxJpaRepositoriesRegistrar extends RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport {

  @Override
  protected Class<? extends Annotation> getAnnotation() {
    return EnableXxxJpaRepositories.class;
  }

  @Override
  protected RepositoryConfigurationExtension getExtension() {
    return new XxxJpaRepositoryConfigExtension();
  }

}
```

XxxJpaRepositoryConfigExtension:

```
@Component
public class XxxJpaRepositoryConfigExtension extends JpaRepositoryConfigExtension {

  @Override
  protected boolean useRepositoryConfiguration(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
    //return super.useRepositoryConfiguration(metadata);
    //return metadata.isReactiveRepository();
    return true;
  }

}
```